# Issues with dependency injection in php

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

I looked at the problems here on SO, and tried to fix the code accordingly, but I'm having a hard time understanding why this is not working.

I have a class in its namespace, and I'd like to use the methods from another class from another namespace in it. So I tried:

```
<?php

namespace Main_Namespace\My_Namespace;

use Other_Namespace\Cool_Class;

class Main_Class {

    protected $cool_class;

    public function __construct( Cool_Class $cool_class ) {
        $this->cool_class = $cool_class;
    }

    public test_method() {
        $some_boolean = $this->cool_class->some_method_that_returns_bool();        
    }
}
```

And I instantiate it elsewhere with `new MainClass()`.

This fails, and tells me

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Main_Namespace\My_Namespace\Main_Class::__construct() must be an instance of Other_Namespace\Cool_Class, none given, called in...

I even tried with

```
use Other_Namespace\Cool_Class;

$cool_class_instance = new Cool_Class();

new Main_Class( $cool_class_instance );
```

Not working as well (I think I get class not found error).

Now, if I don't instantiate in the constructor, but inside a method like

```
<?php

namespace Main_Namespace\My_Namespace;

use Other_Namespace\Cool_Class;

class Main_Class {

    public test_method() {
        $cool_class = new Cool_Class();

        $some_boolean = $cool_class->some_method_that_returns_bool();        
    }
}
```

This will work.

What am I missing here? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `I even tried with` this is the way you should do it, which error do you get?

Comment: I get `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class ... not found`

Comment: It doesn't say which class?

Comment: It's the `Other_Namespace\Cool_Class` class.

Comment: Ok, are you using the composer autoloader?

Comment: Nope, but I am using autoloader that I created. Basically, the namespaces correspond to the folders. And the 'other class' namespace is in a separate folder.

Comment: Please add the autoloader code, it doesn't seem to work. Does it work for other classes? You're probably using composer anyway so I usually just recommend using it

Comment: It works perfectly for other classes, just not this. It's this one: https://github.com/infinum/wp-boilerplate/blob/master/wp-content/themes/init_theme_name/lib/autoloader.php

Comment: Oh, and I work in WordPress, so I cannot use composer for autoloading :(

Comment: Then you'll need to `require` the file your classes are defined in, or do *something* to load the actual code. Otherwise, yes, the class won't be defined.

Comment: And please keep it to one coherent question and one coherent error message within the question. *I tried this, I tried that, maybe I got some error*… That's not very answerable. Give us the best attempt that you think should work, and tell us the error you got.

Comment: I'll try to debug the autoloader, and if I get somewhere I'll post in the question the result, sorry if it seems off topic.

Comment: Please don't add answers to your question.

Comment: Seeing as I cannot add an answer, that seemed like a good option...

Answer (score 1):

For the first example:

```
$myObject = new MainClass();
```

The error you get is expected. You cannot call an empty constructor for a class that has a constructor with a typed parameter.

For the second example (calling a constructor with an initialized object as a parameter, which fails):

<sup>Edit: added details missing in the original quesion.</sup>

1. Please specify exact error message that you received - *class load error*
2. Please specify PHP version - *7.1*
3. Please provide the custom autoloader - *link in comment.*

## I suggest to debug the autoloader by dumping the values it is processing.

Example 3 is ok.

Comment: Error message and autoloader are in the comments in the question, and the php version is 7.1

Comment: @dingo_d I suggest that you could debug the autoloader. try dumping/logging the values just before it fails. Stack trace will help with that

Comment: I'll debug the autoloader, although it's odd that other classes are working fine.